# "Love is for real" or "Love is real"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which one of these sentences is correct:

> 1. "Love is for real"
> 2. "Love is real"

Please give me a relatively comprehensive answer which indicates which one is correct and why, and if both of them are correct, in which situation we have to use each one.

Comment: "For real" is an idiom, which cannot be analysed because it is internally ungrammatical. As Ricky says, it has a colloquial feel to it.

Comment: When one speaks of love there is nothing that is correct and nothing that is incorrect.

Comment: Both phrases sound as inane as "do you believe in love?". Apart from teenagers, who says things like this, and what's their IQ?

Comment: Is sentence No.1 the lyrics to a song? Is that why you asked the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different things.

> Love is real.

This means love exists. No more and no less. It's there. It's not a hypothesis, nor someone's fantasy.

> Love is for real.

Has a colloquial touch to it; not quite formal. It means that the consequences, attendant effects, outcome, etc, of loving someone (such as happiness, suffering, moral issues, immoral solutions, chivalry, baseness, elation, depression, etc, etc) do exist and will be felt by the parties concerned.

Comment: So, as I understood, "Love is for real" is more romantic (and maybe a better choice to use in a novel). On the other hand, "love is real" can be interpreted just as a news or something which informs others. Am I correct??

Comment: @Unknown It depends on context. I wouldn't consider "Love is for real" as being more romantic. It may even be less so, as "Love is real" is a more absolute and definitive statement.

Answer (score 1):

Without any more context it is hard to say what exactly you are looking for, but if something is **for real** it is serious, genuine, and not fake.

For example, if you say **"my love is for real"** it means your love is genuine and you are honest about your feelings.

And if something is **'real'** it actually exists in fact and it is not imaginary. For example: *"My little brother thinks Santa Claus is real."*

Comment: and what about the other sentence (i.e. "love is real")? Does it have a same meaning??

Comment: @Unknown I updated the answer.